# Sample usage of WebViewCompat

Tags: android, webview, androidx

By accident I found that there is a support library for WebView that is part of AndroidX: androidx.webkit:webkit:1.0.0

However I could not find any sample code on how to use it and the JavaDoc is not much of a help either: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/package-summary

Is this supposed to be used by developers or is it an internal library?

Comment: I don't really know either, but my best guess is that it provides a consistent javascript implementation on all platforms.

Comment: Found a video from the 2018 Android Dev Summit explaining the new WebViewCompat inside Android X: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGZYtDZhOEQ But it does not contain useful code examples: :(

Answer (score 9):

This library is an `androidx` abstraction for `WebKit` (as it relies on an update-able APK).

[WebViewCompat.java](https://github.com/mixi-inc/Android-Device-Compatibility/blob/master/AndroidDeviceCompatibility/src/main/java/jp/mixi/compatibility/android/webkit/WebViewCompat.java) itself tells "do not instantiate this" (and also the XML tag is unknown, so one has to use `android.webkit.WebView`); but class [WebViewCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewCompat.html) has several `public static` methods, which are accessible; Also [WebViewFeature](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewFeature) seems relevant (the IDE complained).

When using these imports:

```
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponseCompat;
import androidx.webkit.WebResourceErrorCompat;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewClientCompat;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewFeature;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewCompat;
```

using [WebViewClientCompat](https://androidx.de/androidx/webkit/WebViewClientCompat.html) works about like this:

```
private WebView mWebView;

...
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientCompat(){

        @Override
        public void onPageCommitVisible(@NonNull WebView view, @NonNull String url) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(@NonNull WebView view, @NonNull WebResourceRequest request, @NonNull WebResourceErrorCompat error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(@NonNull WebView view, @NonNull WebResourceRequest request, @NonNull WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSafeBrowsingHit(@NonNull WebView view, @NonNull WebResourceRequest request, int threatType, @NonNull SafeBrowsingResponseCompat callback) {
            super.onSafeBrowsingHit(view, request, threatType, callback);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(@NonNull WebView view, @NonNull WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }
    });
}
```

implementing `interface` [WebViewCompat.VisualStateCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewCompat.VisualStateCallback.html) works alike this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.VISUAL_STATE_CALLBACK)) {
    final int mVisualStateCallbackId = 500;
    WebViewCompat.postVisualStateCallback(mWebView, mVisualStateCallbackId, new WebViewCompat.VisualStateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(long requestId) {
            if (requestId == mVisualStateCallbackId) {
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you know the benefits of doing the above?

Comment: @TomTasche as stated: `it relies on an update-able APK` and not the framework's `WebKit` implementation. name `Compat` almost always means that it's an abstraction... and so the `interface` methods look quite the same, but the engine used may be another.

Comment: `WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported()` also hints for different implementations ...

Comment: well porting over to WebViewCompat was a waste of time it seems.